# Modeling and Simulation in Java

Tags: java

I am looking into using Java to be able to model/simulate (MODSIM) discrete and continuous systems in the areas of traffic modeling, birth/death process, spread of disease etc. I have a working knowledge of Java. I have a good grasp of calculus and differential equations.

I am looking for a MODSIM software that is:

a)Free and Java based

b)Does most of the graphics/animation and allows for 3D Visualization

c)Allows for Java Extensions

I looked at the following software:

a)NetLogo - allows Java extensions but is based on writing procedures.

b)Greenfoot - based in Java and allows for Java Extensions

For modeling the kind of systems that I have mentioned in the first paragraph of my question:

1) Is Greenfoot a good choice ?

2) What other Java based MODSIM tools would you recommend?

Thank you!
Hop

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in agent based simulations, I'd recommend [RePast](http://repast.sourceforge.net/). Anyway, I've recently been searching for something similar and unfortunatelly I didn't find anything interesting. We've ended up writing our software at our university.

PS: Never heared of Greenfoot, sorry

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the answer! I will look into RePast. Greenfoot is from the maker of BlueJ. When you say you ended up writing your own software, do you mean you used Java/Java3D?

Comment: Well university has working solution written in Delphi. So we were like reimplementing pieces to Java, but 3D part still remains in Delphi afaik. Also some guys were using SimPy and mentioned that it was pretty good, but that one is for Python.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Members - I would be grateful for any replies!